# Помощь с ботом телеграм

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть обменник кроптовалют. И при вводе количества допустим 0,00123 выходит ошибка

```
File "C:\Users\adminkropal\Desktop\kropal\make_bot_great_again.py", line 612, in exchange_wallet
res = calculator(float(message.text), data.get('currency'), "RUB")
```

Я так понял что у меня только настроено на 0.00123 с "." а нужно сделать что-бы было "," - запятую.

Вот код

```
@dp.message_handler(state=ExchangeForm.amount, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def exchange_wallet(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
data = await state.get_data()
res = calculator(float(message.text), data.get('currency'), "RUB")
```

Comment: `string = "0,666" `
`string = string.replace(",", ".")`
Только проверку осуществите на наличие "`,`"

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал так
res = calculator(float((message.text).replace(',','.')), data.get('currency'), "RUB")
replace() помог.